# Problem redoing with yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet, undo

I have had a problem with undoing lately, which seems rather dangerous and has
almost lost me work.  At first I thought it was due to undo-tree, so I
deactivated that.  But it persists and now I suspect yasnippet.  I just got the
following when trying to redo.  (Work would have been lost if I hadn't already
saved.)

```
apply: Wrong number of arguments: #[(snippet) "ÂH  > [snippet
cl-struct-yas--snippet-tags 0 signal wrong-type-argument yas--snippet 2
yas--commit-snippet] 4 ("/home/toothrot/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-20180111.1533/yasnippet.elc" .
175423)], 3
```

Sorry I haven't had time to investigate this very thoroughly, but perhaps
someone has had the same problem.

Comment: I can reproduce it with the latest yasnippet, seems to be a bug indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in yasnippet, introduced on **Jan 1st** (not present in any stable release).  See https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/893 for a fix, merged on **Jan 22nd**.  The bug can be avoided by disabling the option `yas-snippet-revival`.

```
(setq yas-snippet-revival nil)
```